# How to assert an exception has been thrown

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, mstest

I'm using MOQ to setup a method to throw a `InvalidOperationException`. I am then using MSTest `Assert.ThrowsException` to assert that the method throws the specified exception. When I *debug* the test it throws the exception, instead of asserting that the expected exception has been thrown.

I've searched this and come up with no examples pertinent to my problem. I've added an attribute to the method `[ExpectedException(typeof(InvalidOperationException))]` but I get the same results. I've tried moving the code that throws the exception outside of the Assert and into its own line of code, but I get the same results. I've not tried wrapping the code into its own method that gets called from the test method because I don't understand how to pass the mock object into a new method as a parameter (what type would I use? The compiler doesn't like Moq or MOQ).

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [ExpectedException(typeof(InvalidOperationException))]
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var mock = new Mock<IFoo>();

        // throwing when invoked with specific parameters
        mock.Setup(foo => 
             foo.DoSomething("reset")).Throws<InvalidOperationException>();
        //mock.Object.DoSomething("reset");
        Assert.ThrowsException<InvalidOperationException>(() => 
             mock.Object.DoSomething("reset"));
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you using both `ExpectedException` and `Assert.ThrowsException`? Pick one or the other. The latter will throw a `AssertFailedException` upon failure, which would not match `ExpectedException` anyway; however, since your `Assert` does hold true (based on your mock), then your assert does not fail, which means it will not throw the `AssertFailedException`.

Comment: Also, is it really throwing `InvalidOperationException`? Maybe this is handled but some other exception has been thrown(too)?

Comment: After your edits, what do you see in Test Explorer? Green-on-screen or red? You should see green in either case.